# How I show div by scale effect and give her text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have div without text and  it's hidden I want give this div a text and show it by scale effect by jquery

Comment: Please go read [ask]. “I want” is not a question, and you are not supposed to just “drop off” requirements here, but show us that you made an actual effort to try and solve your problem yourself already first of all.

Answer (score 0):

try

```js
setTimeout(x=> {
  d.innerHTML='My content';
  d.classList.remove('hide');
  d.classList.add('scale')
},100);
```

```css
.mydiv {
  margin-left: 40px;
  float: left;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.scale { transform: scale(2); }

.hide { display:none; }
```

```html
<div id='d' class='mydiv'></div>
```